# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] as one variable

Tags: php, get

I have the query

```
http://mysite.com/?index.php?var=somevalue&activate=others
```

and need to be passed as ONE variable
like this

```
$myvar = "var=somevalue&activate=others";
```

But without htaccess!

Comment: What exactly do you mean from you question title "*$_GET with no variable*"? The meaning seems to be wonky.

Comment: It was modified, so it would be easy to understand, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: But it makes arrays, when ?var=somevalue&varagain=anothervalue , how to make all together as one string

Comment: @alexvolkow `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` returns a string ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)). You just need to set your variable with it: `$myvar = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Or make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
http_build_query($_GET) # Works with all arrays
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] # Works with $_GET only
```

Comment: http_build_query creates a URL-encoded query string from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php 'd be useful to do this. You can then glue all the pieces of the array together.